# How to wrap word inside a non-editable input type=text?

Tags: html, css, text, input, word-wrap

I am trying to wrap the text inside the input type=text field.I cannot use textarea anyway.

My code:

```
input type="text" ng-disabled="true"  ng-model="groupValue[key]" style="width: 100%;"
```

Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you wrap a sigle line text field ?

Normaly you would word-wrap the output from the field.

But anyway the CSS property you are looking for is [whitespace](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

Comment: I cannot upload the image due to some security issue but my display shud be like below:                                                                                                                                               ColumnName1                   ColumnName2                ColumnName3                  Value1                               Value2                              Value3                             All the columns are inside separate td getting created for ng-repeat loop and the values are inside separate text boxes which are getting cut if it is long.

Comment: Then don't output your values in a textbox, they can't be bent.
If you don't need to edit you values at once loosing the textbox's would be preferred.

But if that is not an option then try and remove borders, padding and margins and see if that gives you the needed space.